# Inaccurate classification predictions by KNN algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I am trying to predict whether a tweet goes viral by only considering 3 variables (for the sake of simplicity):

- Length of tweet
- Number of followers of specific Twitter account
- Number of friends of specific Twitter account

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

all_tweets = pd.read_json("random_tweets.json", lines=True)

# The cutoff value for a tweet to be considered as viral is 1000 (subjective).
all_tweets['is_viral'] = np.where(all_tweets['retweet_count'] >= 1000, 1, 0)
print(all_tweets['is_viral'].value_counts())

all_tweets['tweet_length'] = all_tweets.apply(lambda tweet: len(tweet['text']), axis=1)
all_tweets['followers_count'] = all_tweets.apply(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['followers_count'], axis=1)
all_tweets['friends_count'] = all_tweets.apply(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['friends_count'], axis=1)

labels = all_tweets['is_viral']
data = all_tweets[['tweet_length','followers_count','friends_count']]

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(scaled_data, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 25)
classifier.fit(train_data, train_labels)
print(classifier.score(test_data, test_labels))

prediction = np.array([[140, 3313, 2272]])
scaled_pred = scaler.transform(prediction)
print(scaled_pred)
print(classifier.predict(scaled_pred))
```

This individual components (tweet length, no. of followers, no. of friends) of the prediction variable exactly matches one of the real data points that are considered viral (=[1]) in the dataset.

Yet, I get a [0] (=not viral) as a prediction though it has an around 80% accuracy rate.

Any idea why the algorithm doesn't classify it correctly?

P.s. the K (=25) is chosen by trial and error resulting in the highest accuracy score

Comment: You were expecting 100% accuracy?

Comment: @Chris Haha I wish. My problem is more that even if I would take absurd test values (e.g. [[140, 1000000, 50000]), it still classifies it as non-viral, which doesn't make sense. So I am wondering whether it's just the incapability of this very simple algorithm or whether I am overlooking something

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many tweets do you have in `random_tweets.json`?

Comment: @msanford around 11000

Comment: What is your prior distribution among the outcomes ? (this information is highly relevant).

Comment: @FlyingDutchman [0] = 8972, [1] = 2127

Comment: Your prior is uneven. Take a look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476911/how-are-artificially-balanced-datasets-corrected-for/476948#476948

Comment: @FlyingDutchman Thanks, that makes sense! Could I ask you question via chat (maybe in Dutch, assuming you are ;))?

Comment: Yes - fine with me. I cannot share any mail or so in public via this forum. Do you have a personal website or the like, where I can connect with you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217952/discussion-between-vincent-olivers-and-flying-dutchman).